# Krusader works very slow within mtp folder

Tags: ubuntu, mtp

I can access my android phone using the folder `/run/user/1000/gvfs/mtp:host=XXX/SanDisk SD card` in Krusader. But it is very very slow and krusader shows, that there is no space left in the folder and I cant create or copy files there.

When I use thunar or just the terminal with the same folder everything works fine.

Iam using Krusader on a Xubuntu 16.04